# Jekyll/Rouge - highlighted code blocks nested

Tags: jekyll, rouge

I have switched from github pages to hosting my own site. As a result of this migration I got the syntax highlighting blocs to be nested.

```
<div class="highlighter-rouge">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre class="highlight">
        <code>
        ... ... ...
        </code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

When rendered it looks like:

[image]

The style related settings in `_config.yml` are:

```
kramdown:                                         
  syntax_highlighter: rouge                                      

sass:                                                     
  style: :expanded
```

Setting `syntax_highlighter: none` removes the highlighting related classes (this is just to give more info, the code is just verbatim then, not highlighted in a block):

```
<pre>
  <code>
  ... ... ...
  </code>
</pre>
```

Looking for ideas on how to diagnose this further?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to have been a related discussion about this previously happening [here](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/different-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages-and-locaklly/1084/6).

The solution is to modify a css entry in `_sass/_highlights.scss` so that `.highlight` is replaced with `pre.highlight`