# Why do I get a double frame around markdown code block on Jekyll site?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I am using markdown to create posts for a Jekyll blog with the Jekyll-Now theme, hosted on GitHub Pages. I am highlighting code using fenced code blocks (with three back ticks) and when posted, the code block displays with a double frame. I would like just a single frame. I used stackedit.io to test the markdown, and it looks fine - just one frame. Also looks correct here (see below).

Blog post [here](https://goodmorningdata.github.io/NPS-Clickable-Map-Parks/). I'm obviously new at this with only one post.

Any ideas? Thank you.

#### Markdown

Original markdown also in GitHub [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/goodmorningdata/goodmorningdata.github.io/master/_posts/2019-3-20-NPS-Clickable-Map-Parks.md).

````
```python
center_lower_48 = [39.833333, -98.583333]
map = folium.Map(location = center_lower_48,
                 zoom_start = 4,
                 control_scale = True,
                 tiles = 'Stamen Terrain')
```
````

#### Markdown should display as:

```py
center_lower_48 = [39.833333, -98.583333]
map = folium.Map(location = center_lower_48,
                 zoom_start = 4,
                 control_scale = True,
                 tiles = 'Stamen Terrain')
```

#### Instead looks like:

[image: Double frame around code block]

Answer (score 11):

For anyone experiencing this issue still (like me) and looking for the actual bugfix since the OP never actually said how they fixed it here you go:

In the `_sass/_highlights.scss` file you simply need to replace `.highlight` with `pre.highlight`. It appears that some styling can be applied twice if this is not specified. I also had a entry in `pre.highlight{...}` that I changed from `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow: auto;` in order to hide the scroll bars if they are not necessary.

BEFORE:

```
.highlight{
    ...
    overflow: scroll;
    ...
}
```

AFTER:

```
pre.highlight{
    ...
    overflow: auto;
    ...
}
```

It appears the original issue was with some Jekyll templates that people are running into still. I found the answer from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305080/jekyll-rouge-highlighted-code-blocks-nested) which referenced [this thread](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/different-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages-and-locaklly/1084/14) if anyone wants more info.

Comment: If you find the font is still too large, as I do, which means you get more scrollbars than you would like, add `font: small` in the same place as `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Kramdown supports regular (indented) and fenced code blocks, though [its syntax](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#fenced-code-blocks) differs from the triple-backick GitHub-style you're using:

> kramdown also supports an alternative syntax for code blocks which does not use indented blocks but delimiting lines. The starting line needs to begin with three or more tilde characters (`~`) and the closing line needs to have at least the number of tildes the starting line has.
>
> …
>
> You can tell kramdown the language of a code block by using an IAL:
>
> ```
> ~~~
> def what?
>   42
> end
> ~~~
> {: .language-ruby}
> ```

In your case, something like

```
~~~
center_lower_48 = [39.833333, -98.583333]
map = folium.Map(location = center_lower_48,
                 zoom_start = 4,
                 control_scale = True,
                 tiles = 'Stamen Terrain')
~~~
{: .language-python}
```

should do it. Note that *neither* of these is [standard Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

(The frame you're currently seeing probably results from kramdown nesting several code blocks.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work. I thought it might be the indents, so I tried just 3 x tilde and then one line with no indents and then 3 x tilde but I still get the double frame. See "Test code block." here: https://goodmorningdata.github.io/NPS-Clickable-Map-Parks/

Comment: Are you sure you're [using kramdown](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/)?

Comment: Yes, it is Kramdown, but there is a bug in a scss file in the Jekyll template which was causing the double frame. Fixed now. Thank you so much for replying.

Answer (score -2):

I discovered that this is a bug with the Jekyll template. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This is not an answer.