# Github Pages - markdown for better rendering of code snippets

Tags: markdown, github-pages, blogs, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to add a code snippet on blog post I am making using Github Pages & this what it looks like.

---

[image]

---

A double-framed horror occupying a huge amount of space for just a few lines of code.

I have tried different kinds of markdown

1. <pre><code> block
2. 4 spaces
3. triple backtick

I am unable to get it to render any better.

I am using the default styles etc forked from jekylnow.

Are there any tricks I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

Markdown

Hello

```
function try(no) 
{
    while (no)
    {
        ...
        ....
    }
    return no;  
}
```

---

Hello

```
function try(no) 
{
    while (no)
    {
        ...
        ....
    }
    return no;  
}
```

---

Hello

```js
function try(no) 
{
    while (no)
    {
        ...
        ....
    }
    return no;  
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your Markdown?

Comment: @cherrywoods - I have updated with markdown - but you would have to click edit to see the source.

Comment: Oh yeah, all right, I forgot about that... Maybe you could otherwise add the link to the github repository so we can see source and result?

Comment: This is more of a CSS problem, than a markdown problem, any of the methods you stated should work. But more importantly, you should post the resulting HTML too

Comment: It looks like [this bugfix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059539/4309850) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by @lukehod in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059539/500312)...

In the _sass/_highlights.scss file you simply need to replace .highlight with pre.highlight. It appears that some styling can be applied twice if this is not specified. I also had a entry in pre.highlight{...} that I changed from overflow: scroll; to overflow: auto; in order to hide the scroll bars if they are not necessary.

BEFORE:

```
.highlight{
    ...
    overflow: scroll;
    ...
}
```

AFTER:

```
pre.highlight{
    ...
    overflow: auto;
    ...
}
```

It appears the original issue was with some Jekyll templates that people are running into still. I found the answer from this SO answer which referenced this thread if anyone wants more info.